# C sharp: how to enable go to definition from feature files using xunit.gherkin.quick

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, xunit, gherkin

VS2019, VS Code
I have small bdd project based on .net core 3.1 + xunit + xunit.gherkin.quick
 Right now I'm not able to use go to definition(F12) from feature files 
 I have installed bdd support plugins and also steps auto complete, but still go to definition could not find reference

Comment: facing the same issue. have you managed to get this working?

Comment: It is not supported yet

Comment: This would be a responsibility of a VS extension or something of that sort. Still not supported as far as I know. If you find such an extension, I will gladly add a link to it from the framework's girhub page.